# Overriding MVC Controller When Controller In a Separate Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my VS solution:

```
Core Library - contains Controllers
Project A - references Core
Project B - references Core
```

Both projects have routing based on the referenced Core Library. However, I want to override certain Controller functions based on which project (a.k.a. "site") is calling the function. I've tried creating Project B Controller that inherits from Core Library Controller, making the Core function virtual and setting the Project B Controller function to "overrides". However, the Project B Controller was never even called.

Is this possible? How can I have the Core Controller functions be overridden by the Projects?

UPDATE: Post is updated based on comments below, but still not sure why this won't work in MVC.

Here is the code for the controller in Project B:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

    public StateLevelViewModel GetStateLevelLandingResults(string State, int level)
    {

        var data = GetStateCityBreakdown(stateAbbrev, level);

    }
    public virtual List<StateCityBreakdownModel> GetStateCityBreakdown(string stateAbbrev, int level)
    {
           return db.Database.SqlQuery<StateCityBreakdownModel>("GetCountsByStateAndCity @state, @level",
                new SqlParameter("state", stateAbbrev),
                new SqlParameter("level", level)).ToList();

    }



}

public class BaseController : XYZ.Controllers.BaseController
{

    public override List<StateCityBreakdownModel> GetStateCityBreakdown(string stateAbbrev, int level)
    {
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<StateCityBreakdownModel>("GetCountsByStateAndCityForPartnership @state, @level, @partner",
        new SqlParameter("state", stateAbbrev),
        new SqlParameter("level", level),
        new SqlParameter("partner", 2)).ToList();
    }

}
```

UPDATE 2 : inheriting controller is just plain ignored. Issue is that project won't recognize the controller at all.

Comment: Are you using any Dependency Injection container and if yes, did you check if there is any defined controller registration pointing to the base controller, always? Does rest of the actions methods (non-overrides or child controller specific) are being called/invoked properly when you hit the controller?

Comment: No dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you describe should work, here is the longer explanation on MSDN on why that is:

[C# inheritance, the virtual, override and new keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Basically, it depends on what type the instance is declared as. For example, if

`A : B`

and `B` has a virtual method

`public virtual foo()`

and `A` has override method

`public override foo()`

then even if a variable is declared as type `B`, but is actually an instance of `A`, `A`'s method will be called.

```
B someInstance = new A(); // implicit cast, this is fine since A : B

someInstance.foo() // call's A's version of foo, even though declared as type B
                   //   due to virtual on B and override on A
```

So if you declared your base controller's method as `virtual` and the derived class' method has `override` keyword, then no matter what a reference to an instance of the derived class should correctly resolve to your custom method. Maybe you missed a step somewhere?

[Edit]

Some code samples from your libraries would help if you need another set of eyes to diagnose what's going on.

[Edit 2]

Further clarified some sentences per comment

Comment: At the top of your post, you say "should NOT", did you mean it should?

Comment: Oh, I meant the issue he described should not be possible. His implementation as he described should work, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thank you! So, somewhere I need to have an instance of the old controller vs. just inheriting from one controller to the other? I will post my code in the original post.

Comment: I have updated my original post to show what I did in the controller classes, which seems to replicate the solution here in this post. Not sure why it wouldn't work other than it being MVC.

Comment: Try renaming your custom BaseController to something else, then changing the route to refer to the other name. Reason being, routes take in a string for the controller name, so if they are the same name maybe the route is referring only to the base library's version of the controller? Override won't help you if it gets instantiated like `B controller = new B()` as opposed to `B controller = new A()` from my example.

Comment: I posted your answer as correct because when I created a separate sample solution, it works. (Oh, I did rename my controller). There's something else going on in my solution that is preventing the proper inheritance. Thanks.